# How to pass localization info from this.context in react component to its child consts?

Tags: react-native, localization, multilingual, react-context

I have implemented localization for React-native app according to this file as LocalizationContext.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Translations, {DEFAULT_LANGUAGE} from '../constants/Translations';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';

const APP_LANGUAGE = 'appLanguage';

export const LocalizationContext = React.createContext({
  Translations,
  setAppLanguage: () => {},
  appLanguage: DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
  initializeAppLanguage: () => {},
});

export const LocalizationProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [appLanguage, setAppLanguage] = React.useState(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);

  const setLanguage = language => {
    Translations.setLanguage(language);
    setAppLanguage(language);
    AsyncStorage.setItem(APP_LANGUAGE, language);
  };

  const initializeAppLanguage = async () => {
    const currentLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem(APP_LANGUAGE);

    if (!currentLanguage) {
      let localeCode = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
      const supportedLocaleCodes = Translations.getAvailableLanguages();
      const phoneLocaleCodes = RNLocalize.getLocales().map(
        locale => locale.languageCode,
      );
      phoneLocaleCodes.some(code => {
        if (supportedLocaleCodes.includes(code)) {
          localeCode = code;
          return true;
        }
      });
      setLanguage(localeCode);
    } else {
      setLanguage(currentLanguage);
    }
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationContext.Provider
      value={{
        Translations,
        setAppLanguage: setLanguage,
        appLanguage,
        initializeAppLanguage,
      }}>
      {children}
    </LocalizationContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and it works fine in different screens but App.js file which is something like:

```
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        // tabBarLabel: Translations.PROFILE_TAB,
      },
    },
    HomePage: {
      screen: HomeStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: Translations.HOME_TAB,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomePage'
    },
  },
);

export default class App extends Component {
  // static contextType = LocalizationContext;
  render() {
    // const Translations = this.context.Translations;
    // console.log(Translations.PROFILE_TAB);
    return (
      <LocalizationProvider>
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
          <AppNavigator />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </LocalizationProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I do access Translation in App component as you can find them in commented lines, but how can I pass related information to some const like tab titles? Translations.PROFILE_TAB is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing this into a service. 
Also I use redux and pass the store in to get user preferences and set them:

```
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
import { saveUserOptions } from '../actions/login';

import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';
export const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'ar';

let _reduxStore;

function setStore(store){

  _reduxStore = store

}

const _translations = {
  en: {
    WELCOME_TITLE: 'Welcome!',
    STEP1: 'Step One',
    SEE_CHANGES: 'See Your Changes',
    CHANGE_LANGUAGE: 'Change Language',
    LANGUAGE_SETTINGS: 'Change Language',
    BACK: 'Back'
  },
  ar: {
    WELCOME_TITLE: 'صباحك فُل!',
  ...
  }
};

let translation = new LocalizedStrings(_translations);

const setAppLanguage = language => {
  translation.setLanguage(language);
  _reduxStore.dispatch(saveUserOptions('user_language',language))

};


const initializeAppLanguage = async () => {
  const currentLanguage = _reduxStore.getState().login.user_language

  if (!currentLanguage) {
    let localeCode = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
    const supportedLocaleCodes = translation.getAvailableLanguages();

    const phoneLocaleCodes = RNLocalize.getLocales().map(
      locale => locale.languageCode,
    );

    phoneLocaleCodes.some(code => {
      if (supportedLocaleCodes.includes(code)) {
        localeCode = code;
        return true;
      }
    });
    setAppLanguage(localeCode);
  } else {
    setAppLanguage(currentLanguage);
  }
};


export default {
  setStore,
  translation,
  setAppLanguage,
  initializeAppLanguage
}
```

I need to first setup things in my top main component:

```
LocalizationService.setStore(store)
...
// add the below to componentDidMount by which time persisted stores are populated usually
LocalizationService.initializeAppLanguage()
```

where I need to get strings I do:

```
import LocalizationService from '../../utils/LocalizationService';
....
    static navigationOptions = () => {
// return here was needed otherwise the translation didn't work
        return { 

                title:   LocalizationService.translation.WELCOME_TITLE,
           }
        }
```

**EDIT**
to force update of title you will need to set a navigation param:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({ otherParam: 'Updated!' })
```

** Further Edit **
The props navigation change hack only works for the current screen, if we want to refresh all screens we need to setParams for all screens. This could possibly be done using a listener on each screen or tying the screen navigationOptions to the redux state.

I'm using NavigationService (see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html) so I've created the following function to run through my screens and setparam on all of them and force an update on all:

```
function setParamsForAllScreens(param, value) {

  const updateAllScreens = (navState) => {

    // Does this route have more routes in it?
    if (navState.routes) {
      navState.routes.forEach((route) => {

        updateAllScreens(route)

      })
    }
    // Does this route have a name?
    else if (navState.routeName) {

      // Does it end in Screen? This is a convention we are using
      if (navState.routeName.endsWith('Screen')) {
        // this is likely a leaf
        const action = NavigationActions.setParams({
          params: {
            [param]: value
          },
          key: navState.key,
        })
        _navigator.dispatch(action)
      }
    }

  }

  if (_navigator && _navigator.state)
    updateAllScreens(_navigator.state.nav)

}
```

Comment: there is a limitation in the service approach in that the static object needs a refresh of the page for it to capture the changed value if you change the language - this I guess is mainly an issue with it being static rather than the approach...